# Javascript selective Cache Control library

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cordova

I need to control which files I cache, list these files and remove certain files(user selected) via some form of Javascript. Is there any Javascript code capable of doing this?

**Notes:**

- I don't need to fallback to Old browswers.
- The files stored might include videos, and their corresponding meta(Very Large Arrays).
- I am using Adobe(Formerly Nitoki) [PhoneGap Build](http://build.phonegap.com), so I am happy to use a built-in workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JavaScript cannot change/delete/add cached files.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, you control the cache using the frontend HTTP server and the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers. For example, take a look at this article: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Alternatively, you have the new offline features in HTML5 if you want a webapp that can run in offline mode. There's a [video about this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoUSIBep1G8). Also, look at the tutorial [on HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

Comment: Thanks for what you've put, I think I might have to make my own library, to make a virtual File-system set-up, made with WebSQL or 'LocalStorage'.

Comment: WebSQL, last time I read about it, has been abandoned as a whle. On the other hand, localStorage can be disabled by users, and has storage limitation which is per-site, iirc. So I think your best bet is to use a combination of HTML5 offline and caching headers on the frontend servers together with cache-busting techniques when loading assets.